Как написать сообщение в канал ботом если пользователь присоединился к каналу?
У меня есть бот на aiogram 2.25.1 мне надо чтобы бот приветствовал нового участника канала (публичного), но сколько я не пробовал бот не хочет видить новых участников, в канал он может писать
Privacy mode: Privacy mode is enabled for Lottery
код:
@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def start1(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
    print(update)
    # тут мы принимаем юзера в канал
    await update.approve()
    # а тут отправляем сообщение
    await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, text="текст сообщения бота в лс юзеру")



как то так
   await bot.send_message(update.from_user.id, "текст")

В update есть много данных, к тому же у тебя написано print(update) как ты не заметил данные from_user.id

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
